# Saving DOMPDF to specified directory and then sending as email

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

Hi I am trying to save dompdf to a specific directory in codeigniter file and then taking the saved file and sending it as a email. I am using codeigniter to do all this work.
Here is the function.

```
public function generateCreditAggreement(){
        $this->load->helper('file'); 
        require_once(APPPATH.'third_party/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');

        $pdfroot  = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
        $pdfroot .= '/third_party/pdf/';

        $dompdf = new Dompdf();


        $msg = $this->load->view('credit_agreement_view', '', true);
        $html = mb_convert_encoding($msg, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
        $dompdf->load_html($html);

        $paper_orientation = 'Potrait'; 
        $dompdf->set_paper($paper_orientation);

            // Render the HTML as PDF
        $dompdf->render();

            // Output the generated PDF to Download folder

//          $dompdf->stream('document.pdf');

            //save the pdf file on the server
            $pdf_string =   $dompdf->output();
            file_put_contents($pdfroot, $pdf_string ); 



    }
```

The error I am getting is that 
`Message: file_put_contents(C:\Apache24\htdocs\faceloan\faceloan\application/third_party/pdf/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`
But the directory does exist , and the path name is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path `.../third_party/pdf/` is probably a directory and not a file. PHP can't save your data as a directory. Specify a filename as first parameter of `file_put_contents()`, e.g. `third_party/pdf/my_document.pdf`.